# Unchanged Azure Dataflow Shows Validation Error On Flow Expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We were trying to copy and transform data from one cosmos collection to another using data flows. We are using query to select the data from the collection, all of a sudden the data factory show validation error:

> Data flow expression uses functions/parameters/columns which are not present in current context

when the `validate all` option is selected.

We did not make any modifications and nothing published this occurred. Also when we try to debug it shows the same error.

How should this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have faced this error before @Akhilesh.

1. Check if the query you have used is valid.
2. Check all the input fields within the dataflow transformation if there is any field highlighted in red.
3. If above doesnt work, then delete and create a new dataflow and add your expressions or queries without any errors. Validate everytime you add any transformation to get a clear answer where you are making the error.

Debug will not run if you have any invalid fields within the dataflow.
There might be any expression field which is invalid and hence u r getting validation error.

Comment: Once worked, will it fail later, that is the scenario for me. It worked for a day then without making any changes it stopped ( the confirmation for without any change was - there were not change to publish, but still it does not work).

Comment: ideally shudnt fail later without making changes to dataflow or its dependent datasets or connections. Else dont save, discard the changes immediately if u get the error when there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still having this issue, but for the people coming here in the future the issue is resolved by importing the schema on the step before the filter/select.

1. Start Debug session
2. Select the Source > Projection > Import Projection

This will update the schema to allow for your query to view the column